# Valgrind detects memory leaks in MKL/LAPACK STEVR function for eigenvalue problems with matrix sizes above a threshold

Tags: c++, valgrind, lapack, intel-mkl

I am working on software that uses the Intel MKL implementation of LAPACK functions for eigenvalue problems. When I ran Valgrind to check the code for memory leaks it reported errors only when using the function 'STEVR', or more precisely the C-funtion `LAPACKE_dstevr`. In order to find out if my interface is the problem or the called function, I wrote an isolated test application. The code looks like this:

```
#include <mkl/mkl.h>
#include <random>

int main() {

    // Tolerance
    double absTol = 1e-12;

    // Problem size
    lapack_int n = 64;

    // Generate random tridiagonal symmetric matrix
    std::mt19937 randomGen;
    std::normal_distribution<double> normal(1., 1.);
    double *mainDiagonal = new double[n];
    double *subDiagonal = new double[n-1];
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
        mainDiagonal[i] = normal(randomGen);
        subDiagonal[i] = normal(randomGen);
    }
    mainDiagonal[n-1] = normal(randomGen);

    // Allocate memory for results 
    double *eigenValues = new double[n];
    double *eigenVectors = new double[n*n];

    // Resulting integer array and integer for leading dimension 
    // allocated/initialized according to MKL/LAPACK documentation
    lapack_int *isuppz = new lapack_int[2*n]();
    lapack_int ldz = n;

    // Eigenvectors shall be computed
    char job = 'V';

    // All pairs of eigenvalues and -vectors shall be computed
    char range = 'A';

    // These values can remain uninitialized (irrelevant it range=='A')
    lapack_int lowerIndex, upperIndex, upperBound, lowerBound;

    // Number of eigenvalues found (output parameter)
    lapack_int m;

    // Solve problem using MKL/LAPACK function
    LAPACKE_dstevr(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, job, range, n, mainDiagonal, subDiagonal,
            lowerBound, upperBound, lowerIndex, upperIndex, absTol, &m, 
            eigenValues, eigenVectors, ldz, isuppz);

    // Free memory
    delete[] mainDiagonal;
    delete[] subDiagonal;
    delete[] eigenValues;
    delete[] eigenVectors;
    delete[] isuppz;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it with

```
g++ -fopenmp -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra test_dstevr.cpp -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_gnu_thread -lpthread -lm -ldl -lmkl_rt -o test_dstevr
```

and running valgrind with the command

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --verbose --log-file=valgrind.out ./test_dstevr
```

gives me 0 errors. If I change the size of the matrix to `n = 65` or any number greater than 64, however, Valgrind reports

```
ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

and

```
==48382== 960 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 10 of 12
==48382==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==48382==    by 0x40149DA: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:286)
==48382==    by 0x40149DA: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:532)
==48382==    by 0xB549322: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:622)
==48382==    by 0xB549322: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:660)
==48382==    by 0xB320DEA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==48382==    by 0xA08AA10: mkl_trans_mkl_domatcopy2_par (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmkl_gnu_thread.so)
==48382==    by 0xCF5D5F4: mkl_trans_avx2_mkl_domatcopy (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmkl_avx2.so)
==48382==    by 0x4D76FBC: LAPACKE_dge_trans (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
==48382==    by 0x4DB57DB: LAPACKE_dstevr_work (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
==48382==    by 0x4DB5430: LAPACKE_dstevr (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
==48382==    by 0x10951C: main (test_dstevr.cpp:45)
```

Of course, being a power of two, the number 64 does not seem random to me, but I have absolutely no idea what the problem might be. Does anybody here? I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and GCC 9.4.0.

Comment: Is this an old version of Valgrind? The memory is for thread local storage (TLS). I'm not too familiar with MKL. Do you need to call some function in order for it to join any threads that it creates?

Comment: @PaulFloyd Not that I know of. The only MKL function I call in my application is ```LAPACKE_dstevr``` and the documentation doesn't say anything about it either. The Valgrind version is 3.15.0.

Comment: I'd recommend a newer version of Valgrind. This should be OK with 3.15 though.

Comment: Could you please try with the Intel oneAPI compilers and lntel provided openmp library with the following command  icpx -ggdb3  -I"${MKLROOT}/include" test_dstevr.cpp -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl -o test_dstevr and check if the memory leaks still exists? We suggest you to use latest MKL version 2022.2.0

Comment: @Paul Floyd I tried using Valgrind 3.18.1 but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @Vidyalatha_Intel That did the trick. Thank you. I even found out that it works with the GCC and the most recent MKL version 2022.2.0. So the older MKL version seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for anyone else with a similar issue.
Try using the latest oneMKL version 2022.2.0 which is now available for download and here is the command with Intel oneAPI compilers

```
icpx -ggdb3 -I"${MKLROOT}/include" test_dstevr.cpp -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl -o test_dstevr
```

After compiling, try running Valgrind with the below command and we see **no issues now**

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --verbose --log-file=valgrind.out ./test_dstevr
```